# Output get initialized with U logic in simulation in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am using Xilinx. Currently I am working on a project to develop a pipelined MIPS processor. I have made a component file called Program_Counter.vhd. When I simulate it using a testbench the output get initialised with U and then it's fine afterwards. I can't understand this behavior. Any help will be highly appreciated.

My Program_Counter.vhd

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Program_Counter is
  port (clk,reset,Last : in std_logic;
        addressALU : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        addressIR : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
     ) ;
end entity ; -- Program_Counter

architecture Behavioral of Program_Counter is

signal PC : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin
process(clk)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
    if reset = '1' then
        PC <= (others => '0');
    elsif Last ='1' then
        null;
    else
        PC <= addressALU;       
    end if ;
end if ;
end process;
addressIR <= PC;
end Behavioral;
```

Here is the testbench

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY PC_tb IS
END PC_tb;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF PC_tb IS 

    COMPONENT Program_Counter
    PORT(
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         reset : IN  std_logic;
         Last : IN  std_logic;
         addressALU : IN  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         addressIR : OUT  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal reset : std_logic := '0';
   signal Last : std_logic := '0';
   signal addressALU : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    --Outputs
   signal addressIR : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: Program_Counter PORT MAP (
          clk => clk,
          reset => reset,
          Last => Last,
          addressALU => addressALU,
          addressIR => addressIR
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;

   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        

      wait for 35 ns;
        --reset <= '0';
            for i in 1 to 10 loop
                addressALU <= addressALU + "1";
                wait for clk_period ;
            end loop;

      wait for clk_period*10;

      wait;
   end process;
END;
```

please refer the waveform after simulation.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PC` signal drivers the `addressIR` output through the continuous assign:

```
addressIR <= PC;
```

However, the `PC` not assigned any value until the first rising edge of `clk`, so the `PC` is initially all `'U'`, called "uninitialized" in `std_logic_1164` packge, which is the first and thus initial value for unassigned `std_logic` elements.

The `PC` signal can be given an initial value using:

```
signal PC : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

but it is generally better not to do that, since showing non-`'0'`/`'1'` values in simulation is one of the benefits, as it may reveal actual problems with missing assigns, e.g. due to left out reset or similar.

Comment: So sir I should have to change my clock to asynchronous from synchronous then or is there any other method to avoid it?

Comment: No, my point is don't avoid it; embrace it as a feature.  It is not a problem in itself that signals are undefined at start up; in fact it is just the way that real hardware usually works, so simulation should reflect it.  If you need well-defined values in the design, then add a reset signal that can reset the flip-flop state, either through asynchronous or synchronous reset.

Comment: Thank you sir, I fixed it by starting the clk signal with 1 in stead of 0.

Comment: That does not fix it; it only hides real world behavior from simulation, and so you may face the problem in hardware instead, where it is much harder to debug.

Answer (score 2):

The signal `addressIR` is all 'U' before the first rising clock edge because you didn't assigned any other value to it. The assignment comes from this statement:

```
addressIR <= PC;
```

and is executed once after simulation startup and every time `PC` changes. That is, `addressIR` equals `PC` after a delta-cycle. The signal `PC` is assigned the first time in your clocked process at the rising clock edge. Before this, the signal value of `PC` is defined by its declaration. You didn't specified a value there, so that all elements of the `std_logic_vector` are initialized to the first value in the enumeration of the type `std_logic`. And that is '**U**', denoting that the signal is **uninitialized**.

The simulation shows real world behaviour here, especially if you synthesize the VHDL code for a [standard cell technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_cell). On FPGAs you have sometimes the option to program the initial value of a flip-flop. But, you will have to reset the FPGA design after startup anyway as discussed in the question ["Do I need to reset my FPGA design after startup?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/227945/91366) on Electrical Engineering. [My answer there](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/228379/91366) includes a screenshot of a failed initialization. Thus, **you will have to assert `reset` anyway**.

The value of `addressIR` before the first rising clock edge should be of no interest because the unit which uses this signal value should be in reset too. For example, the instruction bus unit should not issue a bus transaction while in reset.

All components of the whole system should execute a reset at the first rising clock edge.

---

You should include a reset synchronizer in your testbench. Later on, this reset synchronizer will part of the whole system. You will need these declarations:

```
signal reset_sync : std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := (others => '1');
signal reset : std_logic;
```

and these statements in the architecture body (register chain):

```
reset_sync <= reset_sync(reset_sync'high-1 downto 0) & reset_pin when rising_edge(clock);
reset <= reset_sync(reset_sync'high); -- active-high
```

The signal `reset_pin` is the external reset input. If you don't need it, than just replace it by '0'.

Yes, this reset synchronizer uses initialized flip-flops on FPGAs. But, only the flip-flop `reset_sync(0)` is subject to the initialization problem. The value of this flip-flop may be '0' or '1'  after the first rising clock edge after the Global Write Enable (GWE) on Xilinx FPGAs is released. The flip-flop `reset_sync(1)` will be '1' for at least one full clock-cycle.